# Mentor or vouch for another user

Tags: feature-request

At my company we hired a graduate developer about 6 months ago. He has been in the country for a number of years but English is his second language and while getting better he does struggle with the ways of the English speaking online communities.

I suggested he use StackOverflow to help answer questions and also see if he could help answer other peoples questions. However that turned out poorly as his answers and questions were down voted and rightly so, they were of poor quality. His account is now locked.

However I want to help him improve and learn the right way to interact on the site.

Is there anyway, or maybe a suggestion for a new feature to connect with that user and place their questions and answers through a personal review queue.

Just mentioning it I can see many issues arising but if a user of high rep can have the option to mentor a user in some way, we could help guide them through the first few months and set them on their way.

I have noticed that there are upcoming "other language" StackOverflows going to be created (on Area51) and it could be a possibility that ESL users could find these sites easier to engage upon.

Comment: Since you know the question writer, you could offer to work with him on improving his posts, with the aim of getting him unblocked. Once he is unblocked, suggest that he send you his posts first, for review and improvement suggestions.

Comment: [dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212385/translation-help-review-queue)

Comment: Note that there are plans to turn the complete question ban into question throttling instead: [No one likes quitting cold turkey](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230899/163250).

Comment: Question throttling would be a good change. I see it many times, people who don't know how the site works get down voted or banned and hence don't come back. The translation help review queue however also seems like a great option.

Comment: In 2018 this was actually tried. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up However, currently it's not clear if the mentorship feature will be implemented permanently. Interesting to see, that the mentorship idea is really rather old.

Comment: Good to see it was attempted. I never brought it up after this post, the community seemed really against it at the time.

Answer (score 17):

> Is there anyway, or maybe a suggestion for a new feature to connect with that user and place their questions and answers through a personal review queue.

Email, or your chat client of choice.

You know this person in real-life. I'm not sure how the site needs to be involved in you mentoring him. This is a Q&A site with a narrow and well-defined scope. Adding on features to support tutoring users is well outside that scope.

> ...user of  high rep can have the option to mentor a user in some way, we could help guide them through the first few months and set them on their way.

You have that option. There's nothing that needs to change in Stack Overflow to support this process.  Just proof his stuff. If your friend got banned for posting bad content, he needs to work on fixing his content just like everybody else. If you want to help him, help him with that.

**RE: Your comment**

> I don't want SO to provide some form of mentoring platform but maybe a notification when they post something...

If you want to watch somebody's activity, follow their RSS feed.

> ... or as Will as pointed us to a review queue to help those having difficulty with English.

We have a review process: Close votes, down votes, up votes. This is working well, and layering on the complexity of a second opt-in review process is only going to further confuse people, especially users struggling with the English language. We're an *English* technology Q&A site, you're expected to be able to communicate *in English* to post here.

> I'm not going to get him to email me or call me every time he wants to post on SO, it defeats the purpose SO.

That seems to be exactly what you're asking for though. You want a site-generated notification when he is ready to post something, so you can proof it.

Comment: I think you are missing my point. I don't want SO to provide some form of mentoring platform but maybe a notification when they post something or as Will as pointed us to a review queue to help those having difficulty with English. I'm not going to get him to email me or call me every time he wants to post on SO, it defeats the purpose SO.

Comment: @Adam, there is a user rss feed you can subscribe to from a user's profile but I have never even used an rss feed myself so no idea if that is of any use.

Comment: @Adam See updated answer

Comment: Well I agree they need to improve their English and hopefully other language SO's will be launched soon to counter for this. However since we don't tolerate poor English, nor do we have a plan to try and help, why don't we just give each new user an English Quiz, if they fail, they don't get any write access to the site. At least it would reduce the Close Queue significantly. Going through that Close Queue is almost a fruitless exercise at its current size.

Comment: @Adam I can't tell if you're joking. Currently you don't even need to register an account to post a question. We *want* it to be easy, with virtually no barrier. Injecting an actual *quiz* that you need to pass before posting a question is never going to happen, nor should it.

Comment: Actually the more I think about it the less of a joke it sounds. The community has grown to a reasonable size and as such is attracting users that don't fit in with the sites core focus. As such and just for new users posting a question, why wouldn't a quiz before posting be considered. It would stop the torrent of bad first posts by users who never return and anyone within the core focus of SO would easily pass and jump right in. The ease of posting a question has been the cause for its growth but now its the cause of a lot of cleanup.

Comment: @Adam We'll never use a quiz because it would *destroy* the flow of new users into the site.

Comment: @meagar - is there any stats behind that or just an opinion? I know it would filter the new flow of users but why do you want ones we are only going to down vote, close and lock out of the site anyway?