# Reopen audit thinks many okay questions should stay closed

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I keep running into audit questions for the Reopen Votes queue where I think the question should be reopened, even after really thinking about it, but the audit expects it to stay closed.

An example:

- review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/17480231
- question: [sql front end forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163758/sql-front-end-forms)

Many of these types of questions are of course by a novice, and they may not be asked perfectly, but they are excellent learning questions.

What, if anything, do I do about it when I disagree with the audit?

Comment: Looks pretty obvious to me, you need to stop reviewing.

Comment: That question should remain closed. Seems to me the audits are working exactly as intended in this case.

Comment: If you want to help novices that don't have a clear question, the [mentorship project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up) might be something for you. But you should not open their badly asked questions.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: Assuming Alex can help them improve their questions... Considering this audit, I'm skeptical.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth If someone doesn't understand what an appropriate question is on SO, then they most certainly should not be mentoring people in how to properly ask a question on SO.  If they just want to tutor someone in programming (rather than in how to ask a question on SO) then I presume there are sites out there that exist to do that.

Answer (score 11):

> *"Many of these types of questions are of course by a novice, and they may not be asked perfectly, but they are excellent learning questions."*

Then maybe they should be posted on Quora. Not on SO.

We expect quality questions that show some effort, and focus on a clear problem.

This:

> *"what code is used for the front end, user friendly input to a database or table?"*

Is textbook "Too Broad".