# Mentorship research in FAQ?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The mentorship wrap up post is in the FAQ, is this correct?

There is no [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag on the [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up) and it doesn't really seem like it belongs in FAQ.

[image: FAQ bug]

Comment: The post is [not in the curated FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow), no. The [tag:faq] tag and the curated FAQ are different from the automated *Frequently Asked* list on the homepage.

Comment: they are not faq tagged questions. faq tagged questions are an introduction on how the system works. but this one is **frequently** asked questions

Comment: @MartijnPieters still it is a bug. because that question is asked only one time. not frequently asked. There are lots of such question appear in frequently asked q which actually is asked only once.

Comment: @SagarV FAQ means frequently asked questions...

Comment: @AshleyMedway I know that. But in case of tag, it is different. as I mentioned, it is a wiki of how se works. the tag info says _These posts are your quick guide to the what, how and where of Stack Overflow._ and the one you've mentioned is different

Comment: @SagarV it is not, that list, by design, includes featured posts. Whether or not it should or if the label should be altered is a different matter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "ByDesign" also means something that just won't be fixed. So even if its not strictly designed to do that, they are not going to fix, presumably because the effort is high and the impact is low.

Comment: @AshleyMedway: but it was strictly designed to do that. Also, I can't imagine the effort to remove featured posts from that list to take much effort.

Comment: @MartijnPieters from the dup answer "A holdover from the days when Meta didn't have a bulletin." I'd say a holdover means its not by design.

Comment: @AshleyMedway: then feel free to make a new request to have the feature removed. Cite good reasons (*confusion, featured posts rarely make sense in a FAQ context*, etc., point to various reports here and on meta.se). If it is really low-hanging fruit, it can be dealt with with a bit of community push.