# Do we have too many 1/low rep users?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Do we have too many 1/low rep users? This would show that we don't have user retention. Do we need to make the tour mandatory or something along those lines so we don't have a huge problem? Based on the data I could get, we have 8,588,945 users. We have 400,279 users with 200+ rep. This means we have 8,188,666 under 200 rep users. I would recommend for new users to be shown successful questions so they understand how to use the site and make understandable, good questions. What do you think should happen about our extreme amount of 1/low rep users? Or is this not a problem?

P.S. If anyone has exact data for 1 rep users, please share ***all*** of it!

Comment: It's a self-fulfilling prophecy. Those users that *do* understand the site rules do not stay at 1 for long. Making reading the tour mandatory has been proposed before; it'll just be another annoying extra click for those who continue to fail to understand SO's premise.

Comment: @usr2564301 Maybe we should make it **harder** for them to not read it then to read it.

Comment: The number of 1 rep users doesn't matter as long as they ask a brilliant question or give an awesome answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the data you seek can be generated from [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).  However, to the point of 1-rep users showing a lack of user retention, you have to remember that a user could yo-yo between a low score and 1 reputation *fairly* easily.  It is the case that a user with 2 reputation could find themselves with 1 rep if they ask a poor question, or don't post a complete answer, so *that* as a metric for user retention alone is not useful.

What you'd be looking for is when the user was actually last seen relative to their creation date.  On average, [users are active once in about two years,](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/829787) but this average gets narrower up with higher reputation.  Feel encouraged to fork the query and play with it from there.

Comment: Ah, now time to brush up on SQL!

Comment: Ok, so we have 5,763,561 users who have 0 upvotes and 1 rep. Still a problem. I'm 99% sure (actually 99% sure) that activeness is average.

Comment: @GrantGarrison yes, but 5,763,560 of those are one-time burner accounts for one-off homework dumps.

Comment: @Grant: why is this a problem? The site aims to build content, not users. Users are a means to an end, not the goal. Can you correlate those users to a fall in standards, quality content accumulation or other core metrics?

Comment: @GrantGarrison what about those users who just wanted to register, but not asking or answering questions? Is there a problem with that?

Comment: @MartijnPieters let me try to get some more data, but I know from personal experience that new users post bad content.

Comment: @GrantGarrison: some old users post bad content too. Most have learned by then not to do so, and *most bad content gets deleted*, so don't let *recent* bad content be a factor in the equation. New users are more likely to not yet know how the site works, and people discovering how the site works can choose not to continue to post, that's **fine**.

Comment: @GrantGarrison: Then there are new users that don't post bad content, or new users that learn from their mistakes, and *become* good contributors.

Comment: @GrantGarrison: Users lie along a power curve, loads of users that never post, don't come back after a first post, and then as you find users that contribute more and better content, their numbers **sharply drop off**. That's normal and expected. That's not a problem that needs solving; you want a lot of new users because **some** of those do then start to move up the curve.

Comment: @MartijnPieters should we try to teach them how to make good content? Should (for example) the tour be a mandatory thing when you create your account?

Comment: @GrantGarrison: we already make it mandatory for them to read help info, and tick a checkbox at the bottom, before posting their first question. We also give them quality warnings when posts are not well received, when trying to post again. We already **do all this**. Making the tour mandatory is not going to help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so we **can't** do anything to teach them how to write good questions/answers? For example [couldn't we have made sure this user would have known this was meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365046/illuminate-validation-factorymake-must-be-of-the-type-array-object-given)

Comment: @GrantGarrison: we already try to teach them to write good questions or answers. Doing more would have the adverse effect of driving away those that do pay attention and read the material and take it to heart. There will always be a percentage that can't or won't. Universities know that 7-8% of students will drop out in the first year, no matter what they do. Stack Overflow will have similar percentages. **At some point, whatever we do**, we can't shift the percentage any further and can, in fact, make it worse.

Comment: @GrantGarrison: So no, I don't think a mandatory tour or any other mandatory reading materials will shift the percentages. SO *is* acknowledging that perhaps addressing other approaches to learning could help, which is why there was a [mentoring experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up) to see if that could help certain types of new users.

Comment: @GrantGarrison "couldn't we have made sure this user would have known this was meta?" -- This kind of post isn't necessarily the result of a genuine mistake; sometimes (and, I suspect, often) they are ban evasion attempts.

Comment: It's difficult to get reliable data, eg well known SO spammer: : 'do you understand I have thousand old accounts at my disposal? '

Answer (score 0):

> Do we have too many 1/low rep users? This would show that we don't have user retention [...] Or is this not a problem?

[rene has put it very well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365030/do-we-have-too-many-1-low-rep-users#comment567899_365030):

> The number of 1 rep users doesn't matter as long as they ask a brilliant question or give an awesome answer.

Furthermore, as [Andrew T. reminds us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365030/do-we-have-too-many-1-low-rep-users#comment567921_365032), not all users will necessarily want to ask or answer. Anecdotal evidence: my network profile shows I am a registered user in 20 Stack Exchange sites. In 11 of those, I have 101 reputation (that is, only the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/242059)). In some of them, I have registered merely because I felt like upvoting a great post I had seen in the sidebar; in others, I registered to leave a comment (the association bonus enabled me to do so as a new user); in still others, I intended to answer a question, but gave up due to a better answer being posted before I got to write mine.

Comment: Broken assumption.  Any 1 rep user that "asks a brilliant question..." is not going to be a 1 rep user in the data that the OP looked at.

Comment: @HansPassant While it is possible that I have taken a tongue-in-cheek comment a touch more seriously than necessary, I think there is an interpretation of it that isn't broken: there is no problem as long as [a sufficient fraction of the pool of 1-rep users goes on to make good posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365030/do-we-have-too-many-1-low-rep-users/365044?noredirect=1#comment567941_365032).