# Why was my question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, specific-question

I like someone to expand on why my question [Ampersand placement confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107178/ampersand-placement-confusion) was put [on hold] and asking me to edit it so that it asks a single distinct question. It did! From my point of view. Try to see the questions asked by new coders from their point of view and not your own, otherwise you are not being helpful and thus not fit for privilege here, as far as I understand the purpose of this place, which may be an incorrect assumption.

Comment: the on hold doesn't just say "a single question". It says "a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer". Asking for "all the ways" definitely feels too broad in that context.

Comment: You just placed ampersands a bit everywhere. Your effort here is null I assume, or else you would have noticed that the first and last won't compile and the other three *seem* to do the same thing.

Comment: It doesn't show research, it doesn't show examples.  There is almost no text.  If you said you were asking so that you could self-answer, maybe it would be okay, but even there I'd expect text.

Comment: Your question said you were confused but you didn't explain how. What did you expect each line of code to do, why, and how did that differ from what actually happened?

Comment: @BSMP:   I think...honestly...at some point, the lip service kind of has to cease, y'know?  Do you really think that an expert should be answering a question like that?  If it gets put in to The Right Shape™, would that make it more useful than someone looking at the specs?

Comment: This looks like a question copied/transcribed from howework or quiz/tutorial site.   It's contrived code desiged to illustrate some aspect of basic syntax.  Instead of running it through a C++ compiler first, to see what error-messages you might get, you dumped it here as a non-MCVE.  That is not helpful.  'Try to see the questions asked by new coders from their point of view ' why?  I assumed that you posted on SO so that your question could be handled by skilled and experienced developers?  'otherwise you are not being helpful and thus not fit for privilege' that is unwelcome language:(

Comment: It seems like SO policies were overlooked when writing the question. For more help and clarification, you can check SO policies on asking a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: You should also be aware that the skilled and experienced developers who provide so many good answers on SO have seen all this before, many times.  Words like 'confused', 'doubts', 'explain', 'consider' are all flags that nearly always indicate a question that will not meet SO quality standards.

Comment: ' as far as I understand the purpose of this place, which may be an incorrect assumption' - i'm afraid it was:(

Comment: Please update your meta question and explain why you thought it was a good idea to add code in the snippet that cannot compile.

Comment: Your first error was tagging your question [c++]...

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your feedback. I will re locate to www.cplusplus forum/beginner/. I think I just stumbled into the wrong place and only realised it now.

Answer (score 23):

I suppose this kind of goes back to a sticking point with Stack Overflow's ultimate goal.

## Are we here to teach, or are we here to help?

For some people this is an intractable thing and inseparable from one another.  For others, these two things are radically divergent and we have predetermined expectations of the asker.

In my opinion, we're here to **help**.  You're looking for someone to **teach**.

In this scenario I wholly agree with the closure of the question.  This is a fact that can be identified by a perusal of the language specification, and should not really be presented before experts in this fashion.

You may disagree and think that this is an attack against new coders, but...well...we experts have to draw the line *somewhere*.

Answer (score 17):

Honestly, looking at the question, I see two syntax errors and then three more examples that are exactly the same thing except the space is in a different place. I'm pretty sure you either knew some of that wouldn't compile, or didn't try to compile it.

It's like you were holding up a bag of popcorn in one hand, and a chicken in the other, and asking folks to tell you how they differ. When asked to make those kinds of comparisons, folks kind of naturally wonder if there's something odd about the question. I'd honestly be a little wary that someone was trolling, and if I wasn't wary of that, I'd be wary that any answer I could give would seem condescending since I'd be pointing out what's so painfully obvious (or should have been, had you actually compiled that).

I agree with Makoto's answer completely, but I wanted to add that while most of us really don't care about the intent of the asker when it comes to what they want to do with their code, I can see people being a little worried that the intent was simply to exercise their time. We don't have a specific close reason for that any longer because it was applied a bit too broadly, but it's just really hard to figure out what you're trying to ask there, even though you feel that the question is perceptively simple.