# How to deal with questions where the OP lacks the very basic concepts or understanding of issue asked

Tags: discussion, new-users

First - I am quite sure this was already asked in some format, but searching the site for terms like 'user', 'basic' and 'understand' is not really efficient although also  [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364282/can-we-support-users-who-do-not-understand-how-to-debug-their-code) might be relevant but not exactly the same. But if it is a duplicate then *A*: I am sorry and *B*. please point me in the right direction )

My question - which was triggered by me trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992328/space-on-title-tag-make-error-on-html-validator/53992459) is the following :

How to deal with questions where it is clear that the OP has not even the most basic understanding of what they ask for, or in other words, the knowledge gap is too wide to really answer the question.

In the above example question, I somehow struggled to answer, and even more - *struggled to decide if I should answer or not* - as in fact most users just skipped it. but on the same time, considering a `new contributor` I also felt kind of sorry of not answering at all..

It is quite obvious that the OP, who is a new contributor, has no understanding at all of any of the basic concepts, technologies or even tools that they are asking about - and that they probably followed some mechanical guide of producing the code - resulting even in a wrong question title that indicates this knowledge gap. I am not sure I can put this feeling into words but it feels almost like asking about a `symptom` not realizing there is a concept of `disease`.

In numerous occasions I saw some users just vote to close with the closest possible reason. or just move on leaving it unanswered.

But (especially in the case of new contributors), should we try to guide the OP towards the path of UNDERSTANDING the concepts missed - the so called "mentor way"? Or just answer something that will fix the local problem? Or really close and/or ignore it?

Comment: I never post an answer if I don't know what I'm to *really* be dealing with. A classic case happened just earlier in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53992793/1415724). If you're hesitant to post an answer or offer help but they don't respond, then it's hard to know or say if something did solve their question. Up until we know which animal we're *really* dealing with, would be anybody's ballgame. We also guide them to references on Stack and how to post a good question. You've tried helping, so the ball is in their court, if you too want to play their game.

Comment: Related: [The most heartbreaking question: the “Eager, but hopeless”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367893/the-most-heartbreaking-question-the-eager-but-hopeless/368067#368067)

Comment: I usually comment with a polite suggestion to go read a tutorial.

Comment: In some ways, it almost seems like the old "lacks minimal understanding" close reason shouldn't have gone away (not that it's likely to be brought back at this point).

Comment: @EJoshuaS It didn't go away because it isn't actually a good reason to close a question.  It went away because people used it for questions to which it didn't actually apply more than the did for questions where it actually did.  Same for Too Localized.  So now for both we're forced to settle with close reasons that are less specific, and therefore harder for question authors to understand.  If people used the close reasons properly, we wouldn't be in this position.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a dupe out for this, but I feel that there's an answer in merit for this [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question).

There are at least three tenets you should keep in mind when evaluating a question.

### 1.  Assume good faith on behalf of the asker.

This effectively translates to, "Did the person ask a question which was coherent, on-topic and clear as to what they want to accomplish?"  If they did, that's fantastic - it *could* be answered in that context.  If they didn't, then there are deficiencies in the question that preclude it from being answered; you should comment to tease those out if you think they can be teased out, downvote the question if it's just *too* unclear, or vote to close it if it's clear the OP needs time to edit the question into shape and there is a high chance that you'll get people just trying to guess the problem and answer.

Don't hesitate to close questions which are just flat-out off-topic, either.

### 2.  Do *not* assume that the asker has no clue.

This means two things right off the bat:

- You don't get to assume that the OP doesn't understand what they're doing *because* they're asking a question.  If they understood what they were doing, they wouldn't ask.
- You don't get to *comment* to the effects of the above.

This makes the comments you made...*unnecessary* at best, since they don't tease any hints out and could be seen as browbeating the OP into a corner.

Keep in mind that **we're not responsible for mentoring people** that ask questions, as that cannot realistically scale nor will it be long-term sustainable.  Worse, those who want to mentor users into understanding these concepts turn this site from a place to catalog answers to programming questions into a tutoring site, which ain't our goal.

### 3.  If you're on the fence, *don't answer.*

It's better to leave a question which is slightly ambiguous unanswered than have several dozen people pile in and guess at what the question is really asking.  In this context since it really felt like you were on the fence, it'd have been more constructive for you to ***not*** answer.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you opinion is that I should delete my answer ( or not answer in the first place ? ) should the above 3 points apply in the same manner for new-contributors as well ? also, wouldn't that potentially result in a high rate of unanswered questions ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen:  There was *way* too much in the way of "help but not help" in your answer from my perspective.  It could be argued that this question could be seen as *unanswerable*, which is also fine - we can close those and let the system deal with them later.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I think it would result in a high rate of bad questions without answering :-). SO seeks to answer quality questions and for this the question must be clear. Sometimes many think about quantity and others about quality. You always have to look for an intermediate point.

Answer (score -5):

As a teacher (Human Language teacher) I share such frustration and I conduct the matter the following way.

### Be brief and on point

Do not be hesitate to be objective about the question. Do not go into much detail. The person wants to know how to solve that specific point. So just provide the answer and move on with it. That way you will avoid giving away to the OP what are your judgment based on the OP's question.

### Why be objective in StackOverflow makes sense?

Because this is viewed by most of the cases you mentioned (to my little knowledge on the matter by the way) as a place of resources for learning enhancement. An aid and not really a classroom. Trying to give nuances of a specific problem might drift you away from the question being asked. Also such nuances are better dealt at a specific place, such as a course etc.

### Guiding the OP.

When you wish to guide a student or anyone towards a desirable sources of information you, unless given context to do so, should avoid using imperative sentences. You should give closure to the direction with a question. Things such as "Have you checked such or so material in this site?" Allows the person to move on and find whatever answer the person desire, or, enhance the knowledge they need at a suitable place for such.

#### Ultimately I would say:

Have you looked on how to give advices on the Internet? This is a great topic I think it will help you here. Great question by the way.