# How to handle "I don't want a complete solution. Just a pointer in the right direction"?

Tags: discussion

Some posters use variations of the phrase *"I don't want a complete solution. Just a pointer in the right direction"* and I'm not really sure about how to handle it.

I could edit it out, because it's obviously just noise. Also, this phrase is often a very good indicator that the question is off topic. SO is meant to be a database of good questions with clear answers. An answer that "gives a nudge in the right direction" clearly does not fulfill this.

At the same time I want to honor that they are not posting a "write my code"-question. And editing away the phrase would often give the impression that the poster just wants his/her homework done without putting in any effort on their own.

If suitable I vote to close. Is it to blunt to add the comment *"If you are looking for "guidance in the right direction" then you're on the wrong site. SO is a QA site with clear questions and answers."*?

EDIT:

I would not say that this is a dup of [Are "how would I get started?" questions too broad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308745/are-how-would-i-get-started-questions-too-broad) This is about a very specific kind of phrase that does not necessarily has anything to do with being to broad or not.

Comment: I'd say it's a better indicator that a question is too broad, not that it's off topic.

Comment: @Servy Maybe I'm nitpicking a bit now but an answer cannot fulfill "just a pointer in the right direction" and still be suitable on this page. But yeah, you have a point.

Comment: I read that phrase as basically code for, "The actual answer to this question is way too broad for it to possibly be answered, but I don't know how to come up with a more specific question to solve my problem so just try to guess what aspect of the broad question I actually want to know."

Comment: point and laugh, then move on to the next one.

Comment: I hear the hissing of a help-vampire just before it strikes...  (OK, thanks for the tip - can you now help me with some example code...etc).

Comment: @MartinJames Haha, yes.

Comment: A question about "How do I do X with the Y API?" could be answered with "Get a Z context from `GetZThreadContext()`, then call the `DoXWithFooInThread` family of functions your desired `q` value". That's not a complete solution, and depending on the number of functions in the family, working code may be too large for an answer. But a pointer to the right functions is all a competent programmer is likely to need; if they encounter a problem using `DoXWithRotationInThread` that isn't addressed in its documentation, they can ask a more specific follow-up question. So it may not be too broad.

Comment: I think that there is no right answer to this question, since it would depend on the question itself. In some cases the phrase could be indicative of someone who wants to do the work but can't find the proper foothold. In other cases it may be because the question itself is too broad. Perhaps a few examples would be useful here

Comment: @Martin James: Maybe I'm just lucky or am really good at picking my battles but every time I've answered a question like this has been well-received and I never get additional requests. On the other hand, askers that want specific answers anyway often end up craving more specific answers.

Comment: @BoltClock 'good at picking my battles' lol, maybe so:)  I'm wary of such questions.  Many are just too broad anyway since several approaches are possible, [eg: 'use a state machine', 'thread it off', 'use async callbacks'], those I can close-vote.  The remainder I tend to just ignore and let someone else fall down the rabbit hole, if they wish:)

Comment: Also related: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Usually too broad, in my experience, but the OP can often be helped by a pointer in a comment to documentation or similar.

Comment: I think such questions are not too broad, all problem has an essential part and the good answer should target this part.

Comment: @Servy: In my experience, it usually seems to be code for "I need help with my homework, and I don't have even a partial solution to show." Of course, that can easily overlap with "too broad".

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> I could edit it out, because it's obviously just noise.

Specific requirements are not "noise", let alone obviously so. They can potentially significantly change the meaning of a question. As you've stated, editing out this particular phrase would give the impression that the author *does* want a complete solution without putting in any effort of their own and make them look bad.

I would go so far as to blame our collective attitude towards questions of this nature for basically forcing well-meaning authors to put such phrases in their questions so as not to come off as demanding (in a similar vein to pleasantries in questions). But... that'll be a topic for another day.

> Also, this phrase is often a very good indicator that the question is off topic.

The keyword here is "often". Do take care not to treat it as a trigger phrase that automatically qualifies the question as off-topic. You can absolutely offer a pointer or summarize a solution in a short paragraph or a list of a handful of steps, without the question "requiring an entire book to answer", provided the author states clearly what exactly it is they want a pointer for.

The following would be considered too broad — you can't really point the author in the right direction here because you don't know where exactly they need to go (other than to a tutorial or a book or something):

> I would like to display a grid of images with captions. I need it to fit *[so-and-so constraints]* and I need it to accommodate *[so-and-so image dimensions and formats]*. Can someone point me in the right direction?

The following is OK:

> I would like to display a grid of images with captions. I need it to fit *[so-and-so constraints]* and I need it to accommodate *[so-and-so image dimensions and formats]*. I'm aware of CSS grid but I'm having trouble visualizing how to implement a grid system that meets my needs. Here's what I have so far:
>
> *[MCVE]*
>
> I can see that each div (with image and caption) represents a cell but I'm unable to translate this into a proper grid with a set number of columns in one or more rows. Can someone point me in the right direction?

In this example the author knows what they need help understanding based on a specific example within a specific set of constraints, *and* has spelled all the important bits out for the reader (note that it does not state e.g. the number of columns — that's an example of a detail that's *not* important). A text-based answer explaining how grid items are laid out according to a grid template would suffice, and in fact be useful not just to the author but to future readers who have the same preferences as the author.

Someone else down the line *could* add a solution complete with a fork of the author's MCVE, and it'd be up to the author and future readers how they want to respond to that answer (if it doesn't contain exposition, I would either downvote it or abstain depending on how egregious it is quality-wise; if it does, I would *up*vote it).

Nothing about this example suggests that it would take a book, or a condescending "You need to go back and read up on grid layout" comment (believe me, I've left enough of that sort of comment to realize how crass it can be and [I'm making every effort to stop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367976/are-we-collectively-wired-to-be-rude/367987#367987)), to answer. Just a nudge in the right direction, *preferably* over a ready-made solution.

> Is it to blunt to add the comment *"If you are looking for "guidance in the right direction" then you're on the wrong site. SO is a QA site with clear questions and answers."*?

Since my answer basically contests the notion I can't comment on whether something like this should be added in the first place, and while I don't think this is nearly as bad as "You need to go back and read up on grid layout", I don't think my opinion would hold a lot of weight either since I leave this sort of comment myself *and* I'm not personally bothered hearing it in my inner voice. At best, if I were to hear this from someone else, I'd just feel the normal sting that's associated with being told something I don't want to hear (and that's not really something you can help at all).

Comment: Really good answer. It gave me a lot to think about.

Comment: Is it really off topic to write an answer to that first question saying: "If you do need to support IE the easiest solution is the grid layout system. If you have to support older browsers this was traditionally achieved through the use of floats. These are often simplified through the use of libraries such as bootstrap. Lastly in rare contexts (such as email clients) this is achieved through the use of tables." I mean, you would add a bit more detail, but it seems to be a perfect question for Q&A as it would often be googled and give a clean generic answer for future readers.

Comment: @David Mulder: That answer isn't off-topic per se. The question is "off-topic" not in the sense that it's not development-related but by the fact that it's completely open-ended. Your example is just one of any number of possible answers. Easily a question could be a collection of loads of such individual best practices covering a variety of aspects of the subject, but then it'd overwhelm the reader too quickly. That's what makes such open-ended questions too broad for the site.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to check whether the type of phrase we are talking about is legitimate. There seem to be a consensus here that the type of phrase usually indicates that the question is too broad, but I can imagine legitimate questions using this phrase type. I am thinking about questions where a concrete problem is shown with source-codes as illustration and the asker specifies that he or she does not want us to solve the concrete problem, since he or she is just interested in the thought process one needs to solve the problem and the source-code is there for mere illustration that the asker did try to do something.

Example: Someone is showing code written by him or her and an error message, which is not really intuitive and the person thinks he or she is struggling too much to solve the problem, so the asker is not interested in the solution of the actual problem described in the question, but in the thought algorithm, like what and how should be checked in the case such error messages are experienced.

Answer (score 3):

For the special case of an obvious (or politely assumed) homework question, I very much like the compromise described here:

[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

It is a good way of giving exactly the kind of nudge in the right direction asked for.
Even, and especially, if OP actually DOES want a full code given, and only does lip-service to get it, by pretending to only ask for a nudge, this is the right way to answer.

It is of course much more work, to give several hints, ideally with useful (but not too roomy formatting) to support only looking at one hint at a time; for the benefit of future readers who also honestly want nudges.

The future audience for this kind of Q/A pair is only a subset of StackOverflow users.
But maybe it is not exactly a small subset, considering that there might be a whole class finding it useful right now and even a chance on future years of the same class or similar classes.
So the goal to make a good Q/A pair is met, to a reasonable extend.

Comment: I don't think such questions would be per definitionem homework questions, although probably a large part of them are.

Comment: @peterh Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Okay :-) I also think, in many cases, this sentence is only a defensive try from the side of the OP, to decrease the probability of the closure.