# Is being welcoming mutually exclusive to question quality?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, welcoming

I'm interested in people's ideas about this statement:

> Being welcoming is not mutually exclusive to question quality.

I first saw a variation of it in [a comment from the CEO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393155/ceos-2020-kickoff-blog-where-do-you-see-stack-overflow-going/393167#comment750853_393167).

> Respectfully, we do not believe that welcoming, teaching, and empowering new generations of beginners is mutually exclusive with building a quality archive.

And then, the more concise but broader version in the first quote above from [Aaron Hall's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393552/an-account-of-my-meeting-with-the-stack-overflow-management-team) earlier today.

Based on discussions I've read since the welcoming push began, it seems to me that some people disagree with that, but I may be misunderstanding them. Often when people voice their concerns about efforts to be more welcoming, they are stated in terms of the impact of those efforts on question quality.

But do people fundamentally disagree with the entire concept that quality programming Q&A can successfully exist within a more welcoming environment, or do they just disagree with the way the company has been trying to achieve that? I'd like to learn more about the reasoning behind people's various positions on this.

Comment: I agree with the statement he made, however, i don't believe that goal is achievable within the current system. It would need significant, and in most cases, controversial, changes for that to actually happen.

Comment: @KevinB Agreed. The existing system clearly isn't working well anymore, and it's probably not a matter of tightening a few screws. The question is whether anyone in charge has the guts to do any big changes, and whether they'll be the right changes.

Comment: related: [On the false dichotomy between quality and kindness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366774/839601)

Comment: To make it very simple: welcoming means to accept everyone at their own level and try to improve from there. Quality means to only accept things above a certain level. So if not everyone can get there for whatever reason, you have to reject some for the sake of quality or lower the quality standards. Now the question is only if a rejection is unwelcoming or not?

Comment: @KevinB "It would need significant, and in most cases, controversial, changes for that to actually happen." Which changes would that be? If you haven't answered below, maybe just mention them in a comment.

Comment: @Trilarion What needs to be clarified first is what exactly the current course is. Then you can craft the tools accordingly. For example, is it that there's virtually no lower quality limit anymore and we are to be "welcoming" to each and everyone? Then take away basically all close reasons except "spam". Or get rid of downvotes. Or, conversely, should the minimum bar be raised again? Then perhaps retool the entire flow so new posts have to go through a review queue before they'll be publicly visible. There are many ways this could go, but you need to decide *the way* first.

Comment: @deceze I fully agree with what you say but my impression was that they want both keeping the  bar and at the same time being "welcoming" to each and everyone. And they believe that both is possible. You rather argue for a one way or another. (We could even have a new posts pre-publication review queue and getting rid of downvotes.) From a practical point of view, the current course is what the current tools allow.

Comment: @Trilarion Exactly. So far "they" were trying to have their cake and eat it too. Well, after close to a decade of that I'm reasonably confident in saying that that simply doesn't work, and some hard decisions need to be made.

Comment: To a point, being welcoming and quality are mutually exclusive. That doesn't mean we can freely act like jerks... but that "any kind of system with moderation based on quality will hurt people's feelings. You cannot moderate in a nice way."  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390987/4267244

Comment: There is a room for improvement in question asking and moderation process, but no matter what at the end of the day there will always be people that will perceive site as "unwelcoming"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On the false dichotomy between quality and kindness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366757/on-the-false-dichotomy-between-quality-and-kindness)

Comment: this is also related: [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256051/839601)

Comment: @nvoigt answers below: "People want pre-judged content, but do not want to have their content judged" Exactly so.

Comment: @Trilarioni don't think posting such ideas/suggestions here would do anything more than cause a flood of comments in my inbox.

Comment: @KevinB I'm just curious and in general like controversial ideas. But of course you are absolutely free not to satisfy my curiosity. :)

Comment: @Trilarion if you hop over to JS chat, i can point to a discussion we had recently on a... very similar topic

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The problem is that's it's never been made entirely clear what exactly "unwelcoming" is. Everyone understands this entirely differently based on their own bias if the discussion is happening at that kind of single-word abstract level.

What is clear is that there's a big disconnect which is *sure* to breed discontent:

[image: Expected quality spread vs. actual quality spread]

The original vision was for most questions to be at least competent, with some stellar outliers here and there. There was supposed to be a clear red line of minimum content quality ([*"minimal understanding"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257868/476) anyone…?). The reality now is that many—if not *most*—questions fall well below that line, or smack onto it.

All the tooling and original design is geared to deal with the *ideal* case, and many "old timers" hold to that ideal. But that's clashing against the reality of a much different quality spread which the existing tooling is largely ill-equipped to deal with. It's inevitable that this causes friction:

- Many—if not *most*—questions are being shot down. If even just a small percentage of those users start complaining, that's a huge uproar by sheer numbers.
- Internal squabbling ensues about where exactly the red line is nowadays, because it's been eroded over time. Is the original ideal still up to date, or should it be adjusted to deal with reality?
- Those trying to stick to the ideal and deal with reality using the existing tooling get frustrated, since it's simply a Herculean task with no silver lining in sight.

This alone is like a civil war all in itself. **Of course** all sides are frustrated, and "outsiders" feel very unwelcome.

Now on top of that, HQ is talking about minorities and pronouns and whatnot… and it's entirely unclear whether anyone here is *particularly* unwelcoming towards those groups, or whether they're simply caught in the crossfire as everyone else is.

To fix any of that and align question quality with being welcoming, we first of all need **clearer messaging**. Towards all parties.

1. What *are* the actual quality standards? Where is the red line? How are we *supposed* to act?
2. Set clear expectations **internally and externally**. Let moderators (which is *everyone* above a minimal reputation, not just elected moderators) know how they're supposed to moderate. Let new users clearly know what is expected of them. Don't let the *community* communicate it, let the site's design clearly convey it.
3. Adjust the tooling and design to match those goals. No vague terminology. Adjust the tools to work well at the scale the site is actually operating at.
4. TL;DR everything. There are too many rules with too much explanation spread over too many sites and posts. Make it easy and digestible. If that means removing 80% of it, so be it.
5. Communicate using **concrete terms and examples.** I'm pretty sure we could all largely agree on specific examples of certain issues if we see them. You can't get a community consensus if you communicate in vague generalities which everyone can interpret to their liking.

If those fundamental issues are fixed, I believe a great deal of "unwelcoming" will go away by itself.

Of course, this requires someone to actually have clear standards and goals and they must be able to communicate them. That worked well in the beginning with [The Founder Himself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) being a respected individual of reasonably strong opinions that one could generally gather around. Now that this [BDFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life) is no more, the community amongst itself clearly has problems coming to any sort of consensus. It doesn't help that more and more of the old anchor points are slipping away. Not even elected moderators have enough clout within the community to set a clear course, especially if the company doesn't appear to have their backs.

**The company needs to step up here and fill that void.** Either by clearly taking the reins, or by clearly investing into individuals that will.

Comment: Did you just call me an *old timer*?

Comment: Pfft, you haven't even been around an entire decade…

Comment: @rene you post answers on SO basically at a set interval - so clearly a *timer*, you don't have "new user" next to your flare and not yet garbage collected which make you just *old* - so *old timer* as term of a great respect :)

Comment: The company has declared that it has defined quality [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form/). Of course, it didn't define quality there, it linked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests), where it defined "good" quality as `(Score > 0 or (AnswerCount > 0 and Score = 0)) and !Closed`....

Answer (score 61):

You can absolutely have both, but only if you do things the company has steadfastly refused to do for years:

- Communicate ***clearly, up front*** **to new users how these sites are different to other sites with similar-looking ask question input**, like Reddit and forums. Many smaller SE sites do this manually, with experienced users and moderators endlessly repeating the same things again and again in carefully written, friendly but direct boilerplate comments... That approach does not scale, but, *communicating those things* does help. Most people "get it" when you communicate that when asking professionals for free help, you should help them to help you, cut straight to the point, include details and show that you've made an effort. Those who won't even when told are then easier to weed out.

  - The baby-steps the company have made in this direction, like the interesting but excessively debugging-oriented "ask a question" wizard, made a small but noticeable difference; but it seems they're extremely reluctant to do anything to improve the health of the site long-term if it risks any small short-term drop in (bad, doomed) questions asked, even when [the likes of now-former Community Manager Jon Ericson "warned internally that the company was incurring competitive risk by not addressing problems such as the drop in answer rate"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393553/568458)
  - There also seems to be a taboo against acknowledging clearly that such standards even *exist*. Sometimes these sites feel like a department store where management refuse to put a "Pull" sign on the glass door that only opens if you pull it, then they are constantly saying "Why are so many customers coming in angry, with bruised noses? *Is it because you're all not smiling enough?*"
- **Show users more questions at an appropriate level for that user**. Good-faith beginner-level questions are only a problem when they clog the home screens of people who want but can never find the small number of (unanswered, neglected) expert-level questions. There are many ways this could be done: for example, SO already uses machine learning to choose homepage questions based on *topic*, and there's surely more than enough data that an ML system could be trained to notice that a certain question has characteristics in common with questions that users *like you* ignore or downvote but which users *unlike you* upvote and answer.

  - However, again, work in this area, like the [promising but prematurely-axed "New navigation" project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate), was dropped like a stone because solving these problems wasn't considered a priority, and the developers who were working on it  were unceremoniously sacked. There also seems to be a taboo in general around the idea that there even *are* questions at different levels of difficulty.
- **Better tools and messaging**. A lot of what is seen as "unwelcoming" is a misunderstanding about intent caused by poor communication of expectations and meaning. For example, some users find the notification telling them their question was edited extremely surprising and feel like it's a personal criticism or attack - but I'm sure fewer would if new users were given more context, like, *"On these sites, we encourage users to improve and edit each other's questions and answers. It increases your chances of getting a good answer"*.

  - To be fair, [there have been some attempts at this recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow), but in many cases the new wording has been pushed out without discussion or testing and appears to be causing as much confusion as it is reducing ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339762/highly-active-question-banner-is-misleading)). In the past, such issues would have been resolved by sharing the proposed wording with Meta users and iterating on it ([example where that worked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331/mcvexit-redux-i-dont-need-a-milkshake-to-know-when-ive-missed-the-mark)), but ["In 2019, the Community Team was given a directive to reduce our use of Meta"](https://jlericson.com/2020/02/02/2019_in_review.html), so that sort of thing doesn't happen any more.
- **Actually do something to help users who have poor English**. This has been an elephant in the room for a long time: this is a global site, many great developers have bad English, and many (potentially) good questions *and answers* look bad because the authors lack the language skills to pick up on the (poorly communicated) norms and expectations. But staff and meta users naturally skew towards people with perfect English, and the people struggling here aren't being heard.

  - I can't see there being any progress here. For example, "The Loop" survey neglects language and nationality *completely*, and asks about (an American view of) race instead. Almost certainly, when the data comes in, it'll contain reports from many, many users from backgrounds where they use formal English rarely and with difficulty, reporting that they struggle and feel unwelcome, but because the only questions were about *race*, it'll be viewed through that lens, as if the people struggling were (for example) Asian-*Americans*, not (for example) Asian people in Asian countries who learnt English at school and use it rarely.
  - I'm not sure what the answer is, but I'm a native English speaker, so I wouldn't. Probably, there's some tooling that could help and make a big difference, like an optional grammar-checking widget (many exist), or maybe an option for users who know they aren't confident in English to self-flag their questions *and answers* for help from sympathetic users who opt-in to help in such cases, annotating parts they aren't sure about in their own language so speakers or learners of that language who opt-in can help. Things could be done in this area, and it'd make a big difference, but it seems to be a complete blind spot at the moment.

Comment: Opting in to invite review and revision is a *wonderful* idea.

Comment: "*asks about (an American view of) race instead*" yeah, it does. And I severely disliked it. It was exactly at the time SO wanted to show inclusivity and, to me, the race question *completely* flopped . To be honest, my view on The Loop dropped to the bottom just based on this.

Comment: @tripleee I think a big part of the problem is trying to treat all users like they're the same, forcing square users through round holes. Some users like helping unpick what users are really trying to say, some hate that. Some like onboarding, some have no patience for it. If we're smarter in giving answerers the kind questions they like to interact with, instead of shouting at them to like whatever they're given and smile more or else, they'll stick around more, and askers will get better, more frequent, more positive responses. But it needs dev time and iteration, which the company won't do.

Comment: Nice ideas outlined in this answer, but would they actually be enough to achieve the goal?

Comment: "Communicate clearly, up front to new users how these sites are different to other sites": see also [Can we be more welcoming by managing expectations?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377101/can-we-be-more-welcoming-by-managing-expectations).

Comment: Yes, user expectation management is very important. And it doesn't require that much work to get a huge effect. Why is it so bad to present a statement here and there about what is expected (instead of discovery through downvotes)? *"We kindly ask you to stay around for an hour (or so) and promptly respond to comments on your question (within minutes). Otherwise, your question may not be answered."*. And *"We expect you to put in more than the minimal effort. Thanks in advance."* (OK, joking!). ...

Comment: cont': And up front: *"Before anything else, use a search engine to search for similar questions. Often, there will be an answer here on Stack Overflow."*

Comment: Re *"an optional grammar-checking widget"*: Even simple spell checking could go a long way (but spell checking is not enabled by default in browsers - Stack Exchange could provide a few pages with very clear instructions on how to enable it. Perhaps even a YouTube video (though, for some reason, Stack Exchange has never ever been into video)). There is always the problem of false positives with general spell checkers, though. Especially with [all the technical terms with a root in common nouns](http://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_2019-11-01.html).

Comment: But all in all, the most likely outcome is that exactly nothing will be done.

Comment: Proper use of a language by someone who is not a native speaker correlates to  question quality. Although there are tells for non-native grammar from particular language backgrounds, an educated reviewer knows what those are, but not every reviewer knows multiple languages from divergent language groups.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with the comment about poor English. Not being a native speaker myself I understand how difficult it sometimes is to write correct English, and having experienced myself that I unconsciously disregard good contributions written in poor language (not only on SO), I really would like to have some mechanism to improve that. An _optional_ spellchecking/grammar-checking widget would be a real help IMO, and maybe more encouragment to edit questions (and answers) to increase readability (e.g. some hint that such corrections are welcome, and do not diminish the post content).

Answer (score 45):

We're about as welcoming and as appealing as a rosebush.  If you just come at us with little to no respect expecting to be able to get the rose you desire, then you're going to be met with thorns and hurt for a while afterwards.  But, if you give us respect, then you can move past, deal with or even remove some of the thorns to get the rose you desire.

I do feel like we can have a more welcoming environment and that can lead to healthier Q&A.  What I would require is adequate shielding from users who believe that they are entitled to an answer, irrespective of how poor their question may be.

Without that shielding, I'm kinda left to just grow my own thorns, hoping that will be enough...but it seldom is.

Comment: Agreed. If someone posts a question that doesn't make sense or there are things missing people are generally respectful about asking for that information. I feel like that's "welcoming" enough since this isn't a social site. It's when people treat SO as a traditional forum or are insistent that they've provided information they haven't that it tends to be simply dv'ed and closed. Most people are willing to be helpful -that's why they look for questions to answer in the first place - but getting trapped in a circular conversation with someone who provides no effort isn't helping anyone.

Answer (score 18):

> Being welcoming is not mutually exclusive to question quality.

Obviously, this depends on *how* you go about being welcoming.

Many in the community think that quality gates are necessary to keep out bad content - but quality gates achieve this by rejecting content, which some see akin to rejecting people. For instance, just in the last month I have seen people complain on meta that they don't feel welcome because

- My question was downvoted!
- Somebody left a comment that said my question is bad!
- Somebody left a comment that said I'm wrong!
- Somebody left a comment that I am misguided to try this!
- Somebody disagrees with me on meta!

... but seen from the other side:

- How could they learn to ask answerable questions without feedback?
- Isn't it worse to be mistaken forever than to be embarrassed for a moment?
- Should we let them soldier on when there is a much easier, but different, approach?

That is, what is intended as a factual message that focuses on solving OP's problem is misinterpreted by some as emotional message. Sure, careful phrasing can reduce the likelihood of such a misunderstanding, but it can not eliminate it:

- there is no phrasing downvotes
- stackoverflow serves an international community, but what is considered polite or kind varies greatly among cultures. Not being familiar with the culture of the recipient, we can not know how direct our phrasing must be to not offend, but still get the point across

And so, there *is* a trade off between making everyone welcome and offering the most effective help.

And yes, the company is sabotaging quality gates in its quest to get more welcoming. For instance, the question dialog says

> Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research.

But some users don't do that anyway. Realizing this, you want to remind them, and write "What have you tried?", press enter ... and stackoverflow refuses that comment with the message:

> Comments can not contain that content.

So we have a site rule, but the software has a filter to stop us from calling out violations. WTF?

And that's just one example. Another: We have all heard the advice to "don't comment on bad questions. Downvote, and move on". How are they supposed to know what to improve if we don't tell them?

Or how about this: "Comments are ephemeral. They can be deleted for any reason." (particularly if we disagree with them)

So yes, the welcome wagon has eroded quality gates.

In theory, stackoverflow might become more welcoming without sacrificing quality - but in practice, what they have tried so far *has* sacrificed quality.

Comment: You know, I didn't really follow all this but searched for "question quality" on surveying the front page and seeing how many trending questions were, frankly, not good... I'm astounded they did that.

Answer (score 18):

> Being welcoming is not mutually exclusive to question quality.

Yes, it is. And it's very simple. We get bogged down in those super-fringy *$minority* edge cases like neo-pronouns and welcome wagons. But as a matter of fact, many people in the *$majority*, stereotypical straight white male guys, find SO to unfriendly, too. Because what is perceived as most unfriendly has nothing to do with gender or color or sexual orientation:

- People **do not like** being judged harshly for what they write.
- People **like** SO because they find a huge trove of harshly pre-judged
  answers, so they don't have to do the vetting the older generations
  might still remember from forums.

You cannot have that cake and eat it, too. That's impossible.

We can put a little makeup on the judgmental process (maybe we call it "call for improvement" instead of "downvote" or we find yet another term for "closing" a question) and we can have some token initiatives of making someone happy with their personal identity problem, but the elephant in the room will still be trumpeting loudly, even with mascara and being called Xillephant.

People want pre-judged content, but do not want to have their content judged.

There is no way out. We cannot have both. We have to set priorities.

Comment: I expect that there is subset of people who like they content to be judged - there are enough people participating in all kinds of competitions where they get judged, so presumably there are some people interested in they questions/answers being judged... CodeGolf seem to be happy with quite an active judging... Would letting *just* such competitive people to *ask/answer* questions on SO be enough for its goals? Probably not and I think that is the exact issue you are highlighting here - site lures people who can't handle being judged into posting on essentially a competition site...

Comment: I'm not sure it's 100% impossible to have both. Most people want just their content to be answered in the short-term. In the longer term it might then be possible to have the poor content unclosed but barely visible in searches (so other people don't stumble onto it after the fact). I'm not necessarily claiming thisis a good idea, or that I know how to implement it.

Comment: Very few things are "impossible". The things you claimed to be "impossible" are likely not.

Answer (score 12):

> But do people fundamentally disagree with the entire concept that quality programming Q&A can successfully exist within a more welcoming environment

Jeff Atwood himself [wrote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366989/545127):

> I honestly don't believe any system with downvoting and close voting can ever truly be welcoming in any meaningful sense of the word.

Answer (score 11):

**If you want to be welcomed into a *community*, you should be willing to adopt that community's norms.**

**But Stack Overflow is a *business*.**

- **A nightclub is not a party.** It is a business which provides a party-like experience. They have a right to decide who may come in, set opening and closing times, decide what drinks to serve, what music to play, and what norms of behaviour to enforce. As long as you are happy with that, you can have your party there.
- **Stack overflow is not a community.** It is a business, which provides a community-like experience.

**Stack Overflow *Own* the place**

They have the right to decide who comes in, what content will be allowed, and what norms of behaviour to enforce.

Stack overflow are *changing* the expected norm of behaviour, from one of high-quality questions and answers, to one prioritising welcomingness and user engagement over quality. That is why the site is now full of write-my-query, do-my-work, explain-my-homework, each of which gets upvotes, and multiple answers, each of which get upvotes.

This is happening because that is what the *owners* choose to allow.

**They have the absolute right to do this.**

There are many old-timers, who liked the old norms, of "ask a good question, write a good answer, or don't waste our time".

- The question for Stack Overflow is whether they will make more money with the new policies. Management are responsible to *shareholders*, not "the community".
- The question for old timers is whether to adopt the nightclub's new norms, or take their party elsewhere.

Comment: Indeed, it's for the nightclub^H SE to set the rules. The big problem is that they've been rather mealy-mouthed about it, trying to placate old timers with assurances about caring about quality, while at the same time demanding welcomingness. They are for all intents and purposes letting everyone in and are handing out baseball bats at the door too…

Comment: @deceze "Yes we are still the same nightclub you love! We will still have the same atmosphere and music! Just now it's only one night a week. On Mondays." . . . . Yes they are being mealy-mouthed about it, but this transition from quality to volume has been evident for the last 6 years. Their intentions are clear, and fixed.

Comment: I really like this metaphor.

Answer (score 5):

I have drawn a picture to visualize the idea. It's not quantitative really, but rather qualitative and also not really being backed up by data, except that the highest possible quality standards will always imply a lot of rejection and that can probably not be seen as welcoming. Therefore being welcoming is mutually exclusive to question quality in the sense that both cannot be maximized independently from each other. However, there is room to still improve them both, if only one would know how and would decide which direction to go.

[image]

Currently the reports are that the quality is decreasing (see [How is question quality measured in A/B tests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests)) and welcomingness might be increasing (the number of [unwelcoming comments has been cut in half](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/21/scripting-the-future-of-stack-2020-plans-vision/)). This means the current course is (for whatever reason) towards lower quality and higher welcomingness.

Comment: There's an error in your picture, the "currently" marker is up way too high on the quality axis... but seriously, I don't think the graph works too well because "welcomingness" is not an objective thing and its relation to quality is subjective. The idea that asymptotically approaching absolute quality would lead to less welcomingness seems logical, but that's not what anybody is advocating (I'd be ecstatic if people would google their question title and read the first result before posting). Also, the site being filled with low quality posts isn't exactly helping experts feel welcome.

Answer (score 3):

A Q&A site - and a tech foucsed at that - should be about facts, not about feelings. All that welcoming talk is unnecessary overhead that distracts from the content.

Expecting people not to be rude is common sense and has been a requirement for every serious community since usenet times.

My humble take on things is, that someone who's too concerned about feelings should probably persue a carreer in sociology or similar, not in tech. Computers are about logic, not about feeling warm and fuzzy.

That said, being nice and high quality is not mutually exclusive, but having to think about some made up welcoming agenda before every advice probably is.

Comment: "All that welcoming talk is unnecessary overhead that distracts from the content" the original posts about being unwelcoming included *actual examples* of people being *jerks*, so it is not entirely "unnecessary overhead".