# Utilizing Chat to Better Support Troubleshooting Questions

Tags: feature-request

Like them or not, troubleshooting questions are here to stay.  They comprise the overwhelming bulk of questions asked at Stack Overflow.  In this post, I propose some simple changes to the way the commenting system and the chat system interact to better support these questions.

Troubleshooting questions come in three categories.  The first is questions that have been well thought-out, carefully written and need minimal clarification in comments.  These questions are already well-supported and don't require any changes to the system.

At the other end of the spectrum are questions that can't be salvaged because they are too incomplete, too broad, whatever.  You know, the usual suspects.  These can be summarily closed.

There is, however, a broad swath of questions in between these two extremes that could be better supported, but are either closed or simply ignored.  They're not bad enough to remove from the site, but they're not good enough to be directly answerable either.  These are questions that require a dialog between the asker and the community.  In other words, *a discussion.*

Comments are entirely unsuitable for this engagement, for several reasons:

1. You can't have discussions.
2. You can't post code.
3. Moderation is unreliable.
4. Comments are transitory.

In contrast, chat allows more freedom to engage in dialog, have a back-and-forth discussion of the asker's particular issue, in a first-class environment that has all of the tools needed to make this interaction work.

The problem is getting into chat in the first place.  Chat won't work at all for new users, and those with sufficient rep find it difficult to get a chat window started.  There is a link that allows you to start a chat for the question, but it appears at seemingly random times and doesn't do what it says on the tin: *move the discussion to chat.*  And if we're going to use chat for this purpose, we need to *strongly encourage* people to move their discussion there and keep it there.  Otherwise, you're now engaging in the discussion in *two different places;* comments and chat.

So **here are the simple changes I propose:**

1. When a conversation is moved into chat, move the entire comment thread into chat and remove the comments from the post.
2. Disable further posting of comments.  Subsequent interactions on the post to take place *entirely in chat.*
3. Make it easier for users with sufficient reputation to move comment conversations into chat.  This can be done by simply making the "move to chat" link appear earlier.  I'm not sure what the algorithm is now, but sometimes it can take a very long time for this link to appear, and if a high-rep user has decided to walk someone through their problem, they should have a way to get people into chat with a minimum of fuss.
4. Exempt new users from the 20 rep requirement for chat, if someone has invited them into chat for this purpose.

This should satisfy several stakeholder groups.  Stack Exchange gets what they want because making better use of chat will promote the social aspects of the site they want.  Veteran users get what they want because this keeps chatty conversations out of the main site proper.  New users get what they want: better support for their under-specified troubleshooting questions.

Comment: Questions that require any sort of discussion are not, in fact, suitable for the site, and should be summarily closed. The only tooling we need to better support this is better tooling for reviewing and closing.

Comment: Then you resign 40% or more of the questions asked on SO to simply being closed.  I suspect that's not what corporate means by "welcoming."

Comment: And forgive me for being a bit blunt, but I don't think you get to decide this for us.  If I want to walk someone through a problem in chat, I ought to be able to do that with a minimum of fuss.  Didn't think I'd have to defend my proposal so quickly.  Open your mind, @Cody.  The folks who insist on SO being the "Library of Congress of Programming" are hardly impacted by what I propose, and as a moderator, there are significant benefits for you personally.

Comment: It is not what I want for the site, Robert. Your defense is the same as what I hear all the time for why people should be able to ask off-topic questions: if you aren't interested, just ignore it and let others answer. No, that's not how this site works, and it is not how I want it to work. There's a huge market of people who want to ask recommendation questions here on SO, and others who want career advice, etc. None of that is on-topic here, regardless of how much people want it. It doesn't make my job any easier; it makes me not want to do it.

Comment: Would you call this ["Mentorship - Light"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up)?

Comment: @Cody: You're arguing with a straw man.  I never mentioned recommendation questions or career advice.

Comment: @rene: Not really, based on what you linked.  I'm simply proposing some small changes that will lubricate this process a bit, and make the tools we already have easier to use.  I'm willing to entertain reasonable objections, but "I don't like mentoring" isn't one of them.  The crowd that simply wants these questions to go away is not being realistic.

Comment: @rene: Jeff Atwood recognized this need a decade ago, when he wrote about [The Third Place](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/29/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/). All I'm doing here is suggesting some changes that will nudge folks into these rooms when a question needs a bit more help, and comments are simply not suitable for doing that.

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to give my blessing to it in this form. I did recognize that a reasonable number of users liked the mentorship thing so I guess this might be of interest for some experts here. I think we need to work out who to allow to use that move to chat feature for the purpose of improving a question into an answerable state. Maybe make it a silver badge privilege so we can guarantee that those that use the feature know the tag and have enough knowledge gained to not make the feature into a wasteland of empty chatrooms.

Comment: @rene: I don't have a problem with a rep requirement or a badge requirement.

Comment: How about providing the ability to invite to chat as part of closing? That allows people to proactively move questions they expect to turn into a discussion.

Comment: Aren't 3 features already implemented ? When there are too many comments ..the comments are already moved to chat or is moved by moderator to chat( but people are still able to comment).

Comment: @RaoHammas: The idea is to get this to operate without involving a mod.  The system does present a "Comments are not for discussion, would you like to move to chat" link, but it's appearance is somewhat random.  When comments are moved to chat, sometimes people still post comments after it was already decided that it had become a discussion, leaving moderators no choice but to remove the new comments (move to chat can only happen once per post).

Comment: I am trying to understand why are comments problematic (I know they have some limitations and chat gives a bit more freedom)... is it just those limitations on their own or cleaning afterwards? My primary issue with chat is that it is not readable without being noticed. I might want to read what is going on with some question, but I don't necessarily want to be seen or dragged into discussion at that very moment.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Comments are unsuitable for a whole litany of reasons.  Your visibility issue could easily be solved by including a Transcript link with the chat room link (you can read the transcript without actually entering the chat room or being visible to others).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes you are right. though what i think is maybe chat in other window/Tab makes it a lil somehow less interactive (i mean people usually don't try to go in chat room when comments are moved). One of the reason could be because there is no proper highlighting that there is an active discussion going on for this topic. Just a lil msg(comments are moved to chat room) after the answer or post doesn't attract people to chat room. I think maybe properly highlighting this that there is an active discussion on this could be useful. (i might be wrong just my opinion)