# Feature Request: Mentors

Tags: feature-request

#### Post-Mortem

Even better than the link to which duplicate votes currently redirect this question is, I think, this one cited by [Jon Clements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365720/feature-request-mentors?noredirect=1#comment572107_365720) in the comments:

- [Opt in "mentor" privilege at 7.5k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254205/opt-in-mentor-privilege-at-7-5k)

I would love to see something like that implemented. That proposal strikes me as a little more systematic and scalable than the chat rooms implemented as part of the current mentorship project.

---

#### Original Question

This request is prompted by part of the discussion on this recent Hacker News thread:

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16773182

In particular, this sub-thread here:

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16773806

The idea would be that new users could request a mentor to personally help them in their first interactions with the site, especially their first question, and look out for the kinda gratuitous drive-by downvotes I describe in my comment:

> For my last two jobs, I've created a new SO account for that job. I'm a pretty experienced user with decent reputation on my main account. I think I'm a pretty good question writer. I do my research beforehand, pay attention to niceties like formatting and grammar, and try to provide the right amount of context.
>
> My first couple questions almost immediately get downvoted without explanation. Comparable questions from my main account rarely if ever face this prejudice.

This is kinda related to this question here:

- [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow)

I'd like to see people be nicer. But more pragmatically I'd just like the platform to be more hospitable to new users and allow them the opportunity to learn how to make useful contributions before they're quickly turned off the platform all together. It would also allow new users to signal that they're committed to becoming a positive member of the community.

Mentorship wouldn't have to be super complicated. It could be another reputation-based privilege. Mentors could be limited to, say, 3 or 5 novices at a time. The relationship could expire after a finite period of time.

In practical terms, it could be little more than a link between user ids that would notify the mentor to keep an eye on the novice's early actions on the site so that they could gently warn novices away from behavior that may provoke downvoters (who may think they're doing the community a service and not appreciate the negative impact their reflexive downvotes may have) and undo actions against novices that come across as needlessly hostile or abusive.

---

#### Update

Had not come across [the Mentorship Research Project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365720/feature-request-mentors?noredirect=1#comment572064_365720) before I posted (or as I was posting) this. I think that's a great idea and am happy to hear it was proposed, implemented, and reviewed. My proposal for implementation I think is sufficiently distinct to not warrant closing this as a duplicate. But the topic is certainly related.

The major distinguishing features:

- Chat would not primary channel for implementation.
- The mentorship program would be clearly promoted to new users but they would opt-in.
- If an unitiated user (here defined as a user without upvote privileges not in the mentorship program) has a question downvoted, the mentorship program could again be clearly offered to her or him.
- Mentorship would be a new reputation-based privilege and mentors would volunteer to take on novices.
- Mentors would receive a notification when novice asks question. Question could be marked as under mentorship (to signal to downvoters to hold their horses or even offer more constructive criticism). Mentor would have opportunity to comment on and even edit question to offer feedback and guidance. Would also be able to reverse hostile actions by other users.
- Mentorship would expire after limited time.
- Goal would be able to get novice to a point where they could upvote questions and answers. I suspect that's the point at which a user feels they belong. Along the way, it is expected novice would grok community customs and practices.

I have not given much thought to the ways this feature might be abused for profit or for lulz.

I also see now this older question in the **Related** section of the sidebar:

- [Mentor or vouch for another user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260905)

Basically the same idea with a little less detail. And not well received. So I take the hint. But glad to see the problem acknowledged and wheels in motion.

Comment: Extremely related: [Stack Overflow Mentorship Research Project](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353845) and [Mentorship Research Project - Results + Wrap-Up](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357198)

Comment: Certainly related. Funny I did not see that question pop up as I was composing my question or when I searched the terms "mentor" on this site. My ideas for implementation are a little different. (I'm actually not a big fan of the chatroom idea. The top answers on the [original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/) articulate part of my reservations.) Maybe these ideas can be incorporated into the project. Yes, extremely related.

Comment: 'I'd like to see people be nicer', me too but, no matter what we try, new users continually dis us by not reading the rules/policy info they were offered, not checking for duplicates, not making any attempts, posting incomplete code, expecting others to do all testing and debugging for them and other abuses.  I really do wish people would be nicer, but it seems incurable.  So many new users just want their work done for them NOW, and don't care about the volunteers who freely give time/effort to try and help:(

Comment: 'bullies, bureaucrats, or trolls' I objct strongly to this type of labelling.  SO user-moderators give time and effort to help keep SO data fit for purpose, but seem to be the only group to whom the 'Be nice' policy does not apply.  Casual abuse of those who downvote/closevote bad questions is now seen as normal, and any who react to such abuse are routinely suspended. It is true that the abusers are also suspended but, as they have an account-per-question and no rep to lose, they don't care.

Comment: 'Mentorship wouldn't have to be super complicated. It could be another reputation-based privilege' LOL!  'privilege'.  Did you mean 'punishment'?  You think we are masochists here and would freely sign up to having our volunteer time wast.. used up on such an effort?

Comment: @klenwell definitely related on MSE with a staff response as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254205/opt-in-mentor-privilege-at-7-5k

Comment: @JonClements Yes, uncannily similar. The top answer is marvelously thorough and dates back to 2015. Was this ever pursued in any way? I'll reference that answer in the future whenever the topic of how to fix SO culture comes up.

Comment: @MartinJames "bullies, bureaucrats, or trolls" was not meant to label all SO user-moderators. Only the extremely small subset of the community who, well, earn it based on their behavior. I'll edit my question to avoid this implication. I have no issue with moderators who downvote or close poor low-effort questions, especially now that the new tutorial is in place. I'm thinking here of users who downvote without comment or explanation other new users who have given some obvious attention to the composition of their question.

Comment: @klenwell 'users who downvote without comment or explanation other new users who have given some obvious attention to the composition of their question' I hear these things often.  I don't see them when using SO, nor have I seen any evidence that such a set of users exists, and I have asked for such evidence, many, many times.  None has ever been forthcoming.  I have concluded that such users do not actually exist.